# Using a Ruby gem from a Django application

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, django, interop

Lets say I have a few Ruby gems that I'd like to use from my Python (Django) application. I know this isn't the most straightforward question but let's assume that rewriting the Ruby gem in Python is a lot of work, how can I use it?

Should I create an XML-RPC wrapper around it using Rails and call it? Is there something like a ruby implementation in Python within which I could run my gem code?

Are there other methods that I may have missed? I've never tacked anything like this before I was a bit lost in this area.

Thanks

Comment: Can you execute shell commands in Django/Python?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you either:

- Expose a ruby service using REST or XML-RPC.

or

- Shell out to a ruby script from Django.

To transfer data between Python and Ruby I suggest you use JSON, XML or plain text (depending on what kind of data you need to transfer).

I would recommend to use option 2 (start a ruby script from the Python process), as this introduces fewer moving parts to the solution.

Answer (score 3):

It depends a little on what you need to do. The XML-RPC suggestion has already been made. 
You might actually be able to use them together in a JVM, assuming you can accept running Django with jython and use jruby. But that is a bit of work, which may or may not be worth the effort.

It would perhaps be easier if you described exactly what the Ruby gem is and what problem it is supposed to solve. You might get suggestions that could help you avoid the problem altogether.